# a catch-22 situation with apt-offline

Tags: installation, server, apt, nginx, offline

I am installing ubuntu 12.04 onto a HP 1U rack server that is in a lab with no internet connection.

I need to install PHP, Nginx and other packages so that I can run my web app on it that will serve internal clients.

I tried to run `apt-offline set /media/usb/updates.sig` but the server prompts me to install apt-offline instead.

What should I do to install the packages I want and keep the server up to date if it is not connected to the internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download apt-offline from the [Ubuntu Packages Download Page for apt-offline](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/all/apt-offline/download) which is the right webpage to visit to download apt-offline for Ubuntu 12.04. For other versions of Ubuntu just replace `precise` in the URL from the link in the previous sentence with the name of your version of Ubuntu. You can download apt-offline from the pool/universe/a/apt-offline/ subdirectory at any of the mirrors from the list of mirrors on the Ubuntu Packages Download Page for apt-offline.

The apt-offline package is a .deb file, so to install it just double-click on it, and the Ubuntu Software Center/Ubuntu Software app will open, and ask you to authenticate with your password in order to install it.

You can also use the navigation bar at the top of the Ubuntu Packages Download Page for apt-offline to search for other packages that you want to download manually.

Answer (score 3):

Use sudo dpkg -i apt-offilne_package_file.deb to install it on server.

You can copy it with scp sourcefile username@serverip:/home/userdir/, or from windows with winscp

Comment: Good. Apart from the latter bit requiring internet/intranet connection :)